# Xero integration with web system

Tags: xero-api

I am currently working with a company where all of our transactions come through our system called Etrel. We have various Api's containing all the details on these transactions that can be easily integrated with other systems such as Xero. We use Xero to manage our accounts and want our data to be sent across from our system to Xero. Could anyone please provide the steps to be taken in order to integrate the two systems.
Thanks,
Liam.

Comment: Have a look on the Xero youtube channel, there's a video on machine-to-machine operation that might suit what you want to do. You're doing similar to my own config, I have a service that takes invoices, payments, credit notes and a few other things from our point-of-sale system across to Xero, all one-way traffic.

Answer (score 0):

we did more ERP post orders,items,contacts for xero. first you create App using xero developer portal and it have clear document for auth and further process [Refer here](https://developer.xero.com/)